# With PHP, compare two single-col MYSQL tables, adding records from table A that do not exist in table B, and deleting records that do

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a DB, A and B. Each of the tables consist of just one column, email. So I want to check each email in table B against table A, and if it exists, delete it; if it does not exist, add it.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want the record deleted from **both** tables if they match, or only one?

Comment: Both. An easier/more efficient way to do this would be to simply delete the duplicates (both) in one run, then insert the remaining email addresses in table B to table A... So how do I do THAT?

Comment: You want to delete duplicates, then make duplicates? What?

Comment: No... I want to delete the duplicates from both tables, then insert the remaining non-duplicates from table B into table A, or just join the two I guess, sans duplicates (from both tables).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should really do this in pure SQL, without having to muck about with php.

Let's say your table A has column `a integer` and table B has column `b integer`.  Then you can do something like this:

```
create temporary table X as select a from A join B on A.a=B.b;
delete from B where b in (select a from X);
delete from A where a in (select a from X);
insert into A (a) (select b from B);
```

This does the following:

1. Creates a temporary table and insert into it all records that exist in both A and B
2. Deletes from B all records that exist in both tables
3. Deletes from A all records that exist in both tables
4. Insert into A everything that's remaining in B

As table X is created as temporary, it will be automatically dropped when the database connection is closed.

Now, if you need to call this from PHP, you can do the following:

```
$db = new PDO($CONNECT_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$db->exec("create temporary table X as select a from A join B on A.a=B.b");
$db->exec("delete from B where b in (select a from X)");
$db->exec("delete from A where a in (select a from X)");
$db->exec("insert into A (select b from B)");
$db = null;
```

**EDIT:**

If all you need is records from B that do not exist in A, then you can do a simple SQL like this:

```
select b from B where b not in (select a from A)
```